# Why the same font size gives different results?

Tags: html, css, font-size

Why font size is different in divs?

```html
<div style="font-size: 30px;">
    <h1>Sample text</h1>
</div>

<div>
    <h1 style="font-size: 30px;">Sample text</h1>
</div>
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: If you want to overwrite the `font-size` of the `<h1>` element, you should target it directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default value for `h1` tag in Chrome is `2em`.

> Ems are relative to the font size set in the CSS (parent element).

So in your second `div` you are overwriting the `2em` value with `30px` for the `h1` element - font size is now equal to `30px`;

In your first `div` you set the font-size of the (container) div to `30px`, so now `2em` is using this as the base font size - computed font size is now equal to `60px`.

```html
<section style="font-size: 15px">
  <div>base font-size: 15px</div>
  <div style="font-size: 3em">this should be 45px (15px x 3em)</div>
</section>
```